# Movement of marbles on a turntable with no friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-velocity

Question is as the title: A stable turntable with no friction with marbles on it is made to spin by a torque. How is the movement of the marbles; does it fly off the turntable?

I thought that since there is no friction, there's nothing that can provide a centripetal force. So either it flies off with constant linear velocity (since $v=\omega r$) or it just stands still.

Anyone can help me understand what would happen in such a scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With no forces acting on it, if it stood still it'll keep standing still. If it was moving uniformly, it will keep on doing that. Newton's first law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no friction, the turntable won't accelerate the marble.

So if the marble was at rest initially then the marble will remain at rest.